# Formal terminology: metafeatures then groupby (GROUP BY) operation

Tags: feature-selection, terminology, pandas, sql

In ML training and other analytics I often combine features to produce a 'metafeature' and then perform a 'groupby' (pandas) or 'GROUP BY' (SQL) query.

What is the technical term for this operation?

Example, in my work I will combine taxonomy, e.g. the *genus* with a given gene function and gene variant. You could instead consider geographic location of an individual with age and/or occupation, e,g,

| location | name | age | first name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| California | Aderson | 34 | Jill |
| NewYork | Smith | 25 | Mark |
| California | Aderson | 34 | Bob |

Group by operation...

| Metafeature | frequency |
| --- | --- |
| California-Aderson-34 | 2 |
| NewYork-Smith-25 | 1 |

Comment: That's usually handled by the model, not the data structure.  As far as the data operation goes, you aren't doing anything except changing how you represent an ordered pair of fields.  Thus, it appears that any useful answer to your question would have to rely on *how you are using* this result in your model.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks @whuber for your feedback. I will need to think how to word this correctly later today. Terminology is not my strong point.